# Как работает javaFX controller

Tags: java, javafx

Расскажите где почитать, или лучше объясните, в чем заключается магия контроллера. Мне сперва казалось, что JavaFX дружелюбная среда для создания GUI, вроде как в sceneBuilder сделал интерфейс и назначил нужным узлам fx:id, потом создал класс контроллера, к нему загрузил этот интерфейс и пишешь логику, обращаясь к элементам интерфейса по их fx:id. Но выходит что все далеко не так радужно. Уже неделю я ищу и нахожу лишь обрывочные слухи, никак не складывающиеся в общую картину. А именно, что контроллер должен быть сам по себе, без логики в нем, он вроде как грузит fxml, в нем определяется initialize метод, все остальное должно быть в отдельном классе или классах. Ок, так было бы даже удобнее, но я не понимаю, как этот метод initialize заполнять, чем? Как использовать окно, которое контроллер создает и в него логику впихнуть?

Вот есть у меня задача:
Есть интерфейс, сделанный на fxml. В нем определены AnchorPane, VBox, Button и прочие компоненты. Все они имеют свои fx:id.
И у меня есть отдельный класс, который вызывается отдельным окном по нажатию кнопки из основного интерфейса, там без fxml (на java) маленькое окошко, в которое просто вводится текст.
Я хочу по нажатию кнопки, которая через fxml определена вызывать это окно, написанное в отдельном классе, вводить в нем текст и по нажатию в этом же вызванном окошке ввода по определенной в нем кнопке, чтобы текст внедрялся в VBox отдельной панелькой (новая node VBox.getChildren().add() ).

Я это видел так:
В контроллере я обращаюсь к кнопке по fx:id и по методу setOnMouseClick я вызываю второе модальное окно, в нем ввожу текст, нажимаю в нем кнопку и она отправляет текст в VBox по его fx:id (fx:id ="noteList".getChildren().add(текст, введенный в модальном окне). Но я хватаю NullPointerException еще на компиляции, как я понял потому, что нельзя в контроллере ссылаться на fx:id, поскольку он наследуется от Application, и по какой-то там магии в нем не инициализируются поля, к которым у меня fx:id назначен.
Я скорее всего не понятно вопрос описал, но я хочу понять, как мне взаимодействовать из кода с элементами GUI по fx:id, как мне описать контроллер, как мне обращаться и надо ли мне к нему обращаться, обращаясь из кода к GUI FXML?
Вот например, есть у меня FXML

```
<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"  xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
      prefHeight="200" prefWidth="300" alignment="center" fx:controller="App">
  <VBox fx:id ="noteList">
  </VBox>

   <Button fx:id="mainButton" text="Greeting"/>

</VBox>
```

Я не указываю в нем обращение к какому-либо методу в java коде.
Я просто в контроллере обращался к fx:id:

```
public class App extends Application implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    VBox noteList; // контейнер для хранения моих новых node (заметок, в моем случае)
    Stage noteStage; //stage модального окна, чтобы закрыть его в нужном мне месте 
    // (метод SetNote возвращает свой stage)
    SetNote setNote = new SetNote(); // класс, который описывает маленькую TextArea, 
    //в которую я ввожу текст и в нем же кнопка, 
    //использующая fx:id ="noteList" для добавления getChildren().add(this.textArea)
    @FXML
    Button addButton;

    //--------------------------
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("App.fxml"));

        //--------------------------

        TextArea note = new TextArea("pref text \n halo \n pp");
        Button doneBtn = new Button();
        addButton.setOnAction(act ->{
            try {
                noteStage = setNote.showWindow(note, primaryStage, doneBtn);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

       // Add note on main window(note list)
            doneBtn.setOnAction(e -> {
            noteStage.close();
            AnchorPane anchorPane = new AnchorPane();
            Label titleLabel = new Label(titleText);
            Label previewLabel = new Label(previewText);
            note.setText("");
            titleLabel.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 15; -fx-font-weight: bold");
            // set positions of text and buttons in note
            AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(previewLabel, 1.0);
            AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(previewLabel, 5.0);
            AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(titleLabel, 5.0);
            AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(titleLabel, 0.0);
            Button button = new Button("Remove");
            button.setOnAction(evt -> content.getChildren().remove(anchorPane));
            AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(button, 5.0);
            AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(button, 5.0);
            AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(button, 5.0);
            anchorPane.getChildren().addAll(titleLabel, button, previewLabel);
            // add a note in notes list in 0 index
            content.getChildren().add(0, anchorPane);
        }
    });
      @Override
      public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

      }
      public static void main(String[] args) {
       launch(args);
      }
    }
```

Как разобраться в работе с контроллером? На чистом java коде без FXML уже бы просто написал целиком все приложение, без каких-либо проблем. Но говорят, надо его использовать, чтобы разделить логику и GUI. А как прикрутить к коду FXML, чтобы им можно было пользоваться, никто не говорит, нет ни одного мануала, в котором бы этот, самый важный момент был затронут. Зато все мануалы говорят, как fx:id использовать в методах, ссылаясь на них через fxml. Но это не подходит...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Было сложно, но я по...
Кроме шуток. Нашел я ответ. Нигде об этом не пишут, но предполагается модель MVC при использовании JavaFX. Если кратко:
Контроллер не должен грузить FXML файл. Может, но не стоит.
FXML надо грузить классом, который отвечает только за запуск приложения. И этот файл отвечает лишь за внешний скелет приложения.
Логика живет по двум классам, класс с данными и их обработкой, это класс модели.
Класс отображения, который берет данные из модели, через контроллер получает доступ к FXML fx:id и выводит данные. Контроллер занимается инициализацией, он должен implements Initializable и в имплементированном методе, ссылки из FXML обретают плоть. Но имплементрованный метод должен иметь аргументы! Иначе будет NullPointerException.
Все названное выше, не обязательно. Можно все сделать в одном классе. Можно даже без FXML сделать приложение. НО! О его последующем расширении, при таком подходе, можно забыть. Все зависит от потребностей. И да, чтобы View класс, ведающий отображением, видел ваши fx:id, нужно (дальше чистая магия, не поддающая логике) - наследовать Контроллер от класса View. Тогда View будет видеть ваши fx:id.